# auto grow div with between elements

Tags: html, css

How can i make a `div` grow max size to the bottom. and stop when it reaches a absolute positioned `div` at the bottom. I right now have this:

```css
div {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
.wrap {
  clear: both;
  width: 60%;
  display: block;
  heigth: 150px;
}
.img {
  float: left;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin-right: 15px;
}
.right {
  height: 150px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.details {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
}
.title {
    display: block;
}
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="img">
    img
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="hover">
      <div class="title">
        <h5>lots of text</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="text">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <span>some link and detail</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="img">
  img
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="hover">
      <div class="title">
        <h5>litle text</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        lorum ipsum
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <span>some link and detail</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="img">
  img
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="hover">
      <div class="title">
        <h5>Very long title that does not fit on one line with all these words and so on on on on on</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <span>some link and detail</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="wrap">
  <div class="img">
  img
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div class="hover">
      <div class="title">
        <h5>large detail text</h5>
      </div>
      <div class="text">
        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="details">
      <span>allot of details that don't fit on one line and so on on on on on on on on</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want `.text` to grow maximum in height while `.title` and `.detail` can be dynamic in height because of the content.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using Materialize CSS for this design? The way you'd like to design your sections are similar to ["cards"](http://materializecss.com/cards.html). This answer on stackoverflow contains the original code from my example, https://stackoverflow.com/a/32271807/5914723

[Example jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dneilsen22/534r0ynf/)

HTML

Card Title

I am a very simple card. I am good at containing small bits of information. I am convenient because I require little markup to use effectively.

This is a link

```
<hr>
```

CSS

```
.card-image {
  float: left;
  width: 40%;
  height: 150px;
}

.card-image img {
  height: 100%;
}

.right-content {
  width: 60%;
  float: left;
  height: 250px;
}

.card-title {
  padding-left: 20px;
  height: 10%;
}

.card-action {
  height: 10%;
}

hr {
  display: block;
  margin-top: 0.5em;
  margin-bottom: 0.5em;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  border-style: inset;
  border-width: 1px;
 }
```

Comment: This does not provide the behavior i need. Because the card-action moves to when content becomes larger/smaller. But i need that fixed to the bottom of the right content. Then the content needs to occupy the rest of the space.